# How to Make Objects Persist after Running Powershell ISE Script

Tags: powershell

This is my script:

```
Add-Type -Path C:\MyClassLibrary\HidClassLib.dll

$hidDevice = New-Object HidClassLib.CAN_USBPort("test")
$hidDevice.openPort()
```

When I run this script from the command line in PowerShell ISE it runs properly and adds the HidClassLib.dll to my path.

The $hidDevice variable doesn't persist however, and before I can use it I have to retype those two lines. Is there any way to make it so that the $hidDevice would persist after running the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean that it doesn't persist between sessions?  In that case, add it to your PowerShell profile!

Here's a great article on how to do that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb613488(v=vs.85).aspx

Just add the line(s) to the applicable profile and it will run every time a shell opens.